# Attribute Error:'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'is_active' in Flask Python Web App

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Here is the complete error, i have played around with some of the other tabs on this Github, techwithtim- flask web app tutorial around this issue and have not found success being able to sign up a new user.

I have tried to add
login_user(user, remember=True)
login_user(new_user, remember=True)
with no success and tried to delete the database and create a new one, any help is very appreciated.

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /sign-up [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Swag\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Swag\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Swag\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Swag\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "c:\Users\Swag\OneDrive - Bentley University\Personal\Flask Web App Tutorial\website\auth.py", line 59, in sign_up
    login_user(user, remember=True)
  File "C:\Users\Swag\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 180, in login_user
    if not force and not user.is_active:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'
141.133.213.232 - - [31/Oct/2022 15:12:33] "POST /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Here is the file where the error is popping up on line59 at the login_user(user, remember=True)

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from .import db
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user


auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)


@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                flash("Logged in successfully!", category='success')
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrent passowrd, try again.', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email does not exist.', category='error')

    return render_template("login.html", user=current_user)

@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 charaters.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 1 charater.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Password don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 charaters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            login_user(new_user, remember=True)
            flash('Account created!', category= 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            

    return render_template("sign_up.html", user=current_user)
```

Comment: You are guaranteed to get an exception calling `login_user(user, ...)` in your `sign_up` function because at this point `user` will be `None`. What happens if you comment out that line and just leave the line `login_user(new_user, ...)`? Do you get a different exception, and if so, what?

Comment: @LukeWoodward this fixed the bug! thank you so much, reading back the code that does make more sense.

Comment: @ConorSegreti I had the same issue as yours. In my case user class was just implementing db model. I had to extend my class User from flask_login.User which implements the all four properties of the class Ref. https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class Or you can use build-in implementation UserMixin and extend from it. In other words it should look like: 
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the solution was to comment out (or delete) the line

```py
            login_user(user, remember=True)
```

from the `sign_up` method.

This method contains the following code, which I have abbreviated:

```py
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        # ... various elif clauses snipped ...
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            login_user(new_user, remember=True)
```

We can see that the `else` clause will only be entered if `user` is `None`, and calling `login_user` with the user set to `None` will fail. Flask-Login requires that your user objects [have certain properties and methods](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class), and `None` does not have any of these.